# How Do I separate labels and images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am loading a dataset of handwritten images

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers 

train_data= np.loadtxt('train.txt')
print('train:',train_data.shape)      ##train (7291, 257)
```

The first digit of each row is a digit from 0-9(labels), and the rest 256 are images. How can I separate these labels from the images? What I am thinking is to make a new tensor with every first digit of each row, and another one with the rest of the digits. Since I am a beginner I am not sure how to do it or if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn numpy indexing: https://numpy.org.cn/en/user/basics/indexing.html

In your case, just do

```
labels = train_data[:, 0]
images = train_data[:, 1:]
```

Comment: thanks for the link!! BTW, the resulting is shape 256. How can I reshape it to be (16,16) I  am trying images[0].reshape((16,16)), it prints the reshaped array but when I do print(images.shape) it is still 256

Comment: @comms `reshape()` is not a *inplace operation*, which means you should receive the return value, e.g `image_0 = images[0].reshape(16, 16)`, or `images = images.reshape(-1, 16, 16)`

Answer (score 0):

The first digit is label. i.e The first column is label, so if you see it like this

```
col1 | col2 | .... | coln
label| ................
label| ..................
```

Now you want to separate labels from the rest, so you want 1st column. To do so in Numpy, you need to index. The syntax is simple,

```
train_data= np.loadtxt('train.txt')

y_train = train_data[:, 0] # All Rows, col 0 (0 is 1st col since indexing starts from 0)
# y_train is commonly referred as training labels

x_train = train_data[:, 1:] # All rows, col 1 included and onwards.
```

Hope this is clear.